# Does MQTT use AMQP?

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, amqp

I was fiddling with MQTT brokers and created channels and subscribed to them. Today I log into my RabbitMq interface and I find two queues titled

`mqtt-subscription-1qos1` and `mqtt-subscription-2qos1`. I was very confused because I don't know how the two relate to each other.

Is MQTT built on top of AMQP so thats why it creates queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in the subject, No MQTT is it's own independent protocol and has nothing to do with AMQP.

RabbitMQ's implementation of MQTT may make use of queues for clients subscribing to topics at QOS 1/2 in order to ensure those messages are delivered when the client is offline and also to ensure the messages are delivered in order.

Comment: So MQTT is not built on top of AMQP however it uses it to ensure Qos 1/2 are delivered offline?

Comment: I'm saying the RabbitMQ internal implementation looks to be using Queues to store high QOS messages for specific clients.

Comment: What if Rabbitmq was not on the device. How will MQTT store the message offline if it doesn't have a queue?

Comment: MQTT is not product/program, it is a protocol. How different broker or client implementations store messages is entirely down to that implementation some use files, others use databases some just store messages in memory. In the case of RabbitMQ it looks like it's chosen to use a system it already had available.